# Find the expected value of $E[\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)^2}]$ where X is binomial

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, summation

The problem:

X is a binomial random variable, find $E[\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)^2}]$

Using the law of unconscious statistician we get

$$
E\left[\frac{1}{\left(X+1\right)^2}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{\left(1+k\right)^2}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

If I write

$$
\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^2}\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{k+1}=\binom{n+2}{k+2}\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{n+2}\frac{k+2}{k+1}
$$

But then I don't know how to proceed. Maybe there is an ellegant solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

A 'closed-form' solution exists, although I am not sure it is as elegant as you would like. To illustrate, if $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$ with pmf $f(x)$:

[image]

Then:

[image]

... with the help of the `Expect` function from *mathStatica/Mathematica*.

Here is a plot of the solution, as $n$ increases from 1 to 20, when:

- $p = \frac14$ (green)
- $p = \frac12$ (blue)
- $p = \frac34$ (red)

[image]

**Notes**

1. `HypergeometricPFQ` denotes the generalised [HypergeometricPFQ function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html)
2. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors of the `Expect` function used above.