# Analytical form for the expected value of $\frac{1}{(2+X)^2}$ where X is binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, binomial-distribution

As observed in [Find the expected value of $E[\frac{1}{(1+X)^2}]$ where X is binomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879010/find-the-expected-value-of-e-frac1-leftx1-right2-where-x-is-binomial), there exists a closed-form solution to

$$ E\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)^2}\right]  $$

where $X$ is a binomial random variable, i.e $X∼Bin(n,p)$. I greatly thank the author who replied to the previous post (@wolfies)!

**Current problem**: I am now faced with the problem of finding closed-form solution for

$$ E\left[\frac{1}{(2+X)^2}\right]  \text{ where } X\sim Bin(n,p)$$

Any ideas on how to proceed? Is there perhaps a way to extend the closed-form solution proposed by @wolfies to the case where we have $(2+X)$, instead of $(1+X)$ at the denominator?

In the literature, I was able to find some insights inside Chao and Strawderman(1972), i.e. [Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 67, No. 338 (Jun., 1972), pp. 429-431.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2284399?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Nevertheless, an analytical formula is provided for

$$ E\left[\frac{1}{(A+X)^k}\right] \:\text{ where }\: X \sim Bin(n,p) \:\text{ and }\: A \text{ is a constant}  $$ only in the setting where $A=1$ and $k=1$, i.e.

$$ E\left[\frac{1}{(1+X)}\right] = \frac{1-q^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)p} $$

Comment: As an approximation we have $$\Bbb E\left[\frac1{(X+2)^2}\right]=\Bbb V\left[\frac1{X+2}\right]+\Bbb E\left[\frac1{X+2}\right]^2\approx\frac{\Bbb V[X]}{(\Bbb E[X]+2))^4}+\Bbb E\left[\frac1{X+2}\right]^2$$ on expanding $\Bbb V[1/(X+2)]$ about the mean. From Chao and Strawderman we obtain $$\Bbb E\left[\frac1{(X+2)^2}\right]\approx\frac{np(1-p)}{(np+2)^4}+\frac{((n+2)p+(1-p)^{n+2}-1)^2}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2p^4}.$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, thank you very much for your input !